# Execution of SQL query with count function with in where clause

Tags: sql

- `Book` (Bid, price)

No two books have the same price.

```
SELECT bid
FROM Book t1
WHERE (SELECT count(*)
       FROM Book t2
       WHERE t1.price > t2.price) < 3
```

Please explain briefly the execution with some example and result of the above query.

Comment: actually i just want to know how this query internally will execute?

Comment: SO is for actual programming problems, not for explanations how code works. Pick an SQL tutorial, there are many online.

Comment: Why don't You experiment with `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: Also you should turn on `estimated` and `actual execution` plans

Comment: @HoneyBadger provide any suitable link to understand high diffculty of sql queries.

Comment: @ShashankGupta, google.com

Answer (score 0):

For each book in table `Book`, the correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause counts the number of books in `Book` that have a price that is strictly lower. If that count is less than three, that book is selected.

Basically, the query is the answer to: Select all books for which exist at most two books with lower prices.

This could have been written simpler as follows (given that no two prices are the same for any pair of books):

- SQL Server:

  ```
  SELECT TOP 3 bid FROM book ORDER BY price ASC;
  ```
- ANSI/ISO SQL:2008

  ```
  SELECT bid FROM book ORDER BY price ASC
  FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
  ```